# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition timeout if not granted /denied access

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, callback, geolocation

I have a problem which I cannot find a resolution for. Basically, when using Google Maps, the callback on success does not load until the user clicks on Allow or Deny (which will fire the error callback). So for as long as the popup requesting access remains ignored, nothing is shown on the screen.

Is there a way to say that if either "allow" or "deny" is not clicked after 10 seconds then to call the error callback?

Comment: it might help to see some of your code in question, so we get a better idea what you're doing

Comment: It was the basic setup described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Answer (score 0):

I just used a setTimeout function which called the `handleNoGeolocation` function after X seconds. If the user then clicks, "Allow", the success function would execute.

Here's my code:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
          var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            handleNoGeolocation();
          }, 3000);
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            doDirections();
          }, handleNoGeolocation, {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
     }
```